# How to overload << operator in derived classes on c++

Tags: c++11, polymorphism, operator-overloading

In my example, I have two classes: `Parent` and `Child`. I'm using a vector of pointers to `Parent` (`vector<Parent*> v;`) and I'm inserting objects of both classes into `v`. I'm trying to print the classes attributes overloading the `operator <<`. My code prints the Parents attributes (name and age) and I would like to know how to print the derived attributes from `Parent` and the `Child`'s own attribute.

```
class Parent{
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &saida, Parent &parent){
        out << "Name: " << parent.name << ", Age: " << parent.age << "." << endl;
        return out;
    }
    public:
        Parent(string name, int age){
            this->name = name;
            this->age = age;
        }
        string& getName(){
            return name;
        }
        int& getAge(){
            return age;
        }
        
    private:
        string name;
        int age;
};

class Child: public Parent{
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, Child &child){
        out << "Name: " << child.name << ", Age: " << child.age << ", School: " << child.school << "." << endl;   
        return out;
    } // <- Don´t know what to do here

    public:
        Child(string name, int age, string school): Parent(name, age){
            this->school = school;
        }
        string& getType(){
            return type;
        }
        
    private:
        string school;
};


int main(){
    vector<Father*> v;

    v.push_back(new Parent("Father", 30));
    v.push_back(new Child("Child", 10, "School"));
    


    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
        cout << *v[i];
    }
    return 0;

}
```

It prints:

> ```
> Name: Father, Age: 30
> Name: Child, Age: 10
> ```

Comment: One way is to have the `operator<<` in the `Parent` class call a virtual function that you've defined in both `Parent` and `Child` that writes the output to a passed in `std::ostream&`. You don't need the `operator<<` in `Child` then.

Comment: Thank you, @RetiredNinja.  It answears my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Parent`:

```
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream& out, Parent const& parent){
      parent.print(out);
      out << ".\n";
      return out;
    }
    virtual void print(std::ostream& out) const {
      out << "Name: " << name << ", Age: " << age;
    }
```

in `Child`:

```
    void print(std::ostream& out) const override {
      Parent::print(out);
      out << ", School: " << school;
    }
```

and things should work the way you want.

To use C++'s object inheritance system and get dynamic dispatch, you need to use `virtual` dispatch.  Here, I forward the `operator<<` to a virtual `print` method.

This `print` method doesn't include the `".\n"` on purpose; that allows children to add new fields easily.

The `Child` class does not have a `operator<<`, but uses the `Parent`'s `operator<<`.